# Scalar function vs subquery performance (for EXISTS)

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are few similar questions in SO comparing Scalar functions vs subqueries but my question is specific to the following use case. I have an `EXISTS` clause which I'd like to move to a scalar function. Would it incur an additional performance cost? As I understand (which may well be wrong) the `EXISTS` here will anyway involve another query which the scalar function also does.

Here's what I have

```
select * 
from
    A
where
    not exists(select 1 from B where B.some_id = A.some_id and B.something = 'x')
```

What I'd like to change it to

```
create function does_exist_in_B (@some_id int) returns bit as
begin
   declare @does_exist bit = 1
   if not exists(select 1 from B where B.some_id = @some_id and B.something = 'x')
       set @does_exist = 0
   return @does_exist
end

select * 
from
    A
where
    does_exist_in_B(A.some_id) = 0
```

The reason I like to use a function is that this check needs to be duplicated in few other places and I want to keep that logic in a single place (for obvious reasons). So how could I go about it? Will a table-valued function make any difference here?

Comment: I don't think the optimizer will be able to incorporate your function into the bigger query. That being true I think it's guaranteed to run a lot less efficiently and fire off that inner existence query for every row of A. The straight `select` can transform into a semi-join and be handled a lot better. A couple tests on big tables ought to confirm my hunch.

Comment: So with the `exists(select ...)`, won't that `select` be run for each row in the dataset (each row in A)?

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: You will not see actual statistics and execution plan in SSMS (however profiler will help with correct statistics). Your query which uses scalar function will not be able to parallelize.

Comment: Yes, it will run for each row in the dataset, as your query is correlated (B.some_id = @some_id). For better performance Inline Table function for (select 1 from B where B.some_id = A.some_id and B.something = 'x') will be better choice than scalar.

Comment: *Conceptually* the `not exists` runs for each row but that's doesn't mean it's actually executed that way.

Comment: Just for my understanding - how would it get _actually_ executed?